# Find .htaccess files on OSX

Tags: macos, search, finder, file-search

Hidden files are already visible in my computer (I used [Revealer](http://trcdatarecovery.com/software-apps/revealer-app)) but I can't use finder to find **.htaccess** files. I tried typing **.htaccess** in the search field, selected the options "File visibility" = "Invisible Items", "System Files" = "are included", also tried **.htaccess** in the "File extension" option (together and separately in different combinations) with no luck. I get other files in the search results, but no hidden files.

I tried also searching for **.git** files, same thing: 0 items found. Searching for regular files works fine. I'm using OSX Yosemite.

I saw older answers in superuser.com and nothing worked for me.

How can I use Finder to search for hidden files? What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Are you sure that file exists in your computer ? **.htaccess** is not found in OSX by default

Comment: @The_IT_Guy_You_Don't_Like yes I just created a new .htaccess file in my Desktop (the file is not even invisible or hidden) and it doesn't show up in a search with Finder.

Comment: also why the downvote? I did some research, put some effort and I can't find a solution for my question.

Comment: [try this tool](http://apps.tempel.org/FindAnyFile/index.php) else create a new one // tool linked [from](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/55497/90381)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[EastFind](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/easyfind/id411673888) is perfect for this - it "Finds invisible files and files inside packages (something Spotlight doesn't do)". Has other great features like Boolean operators, viewing files in Quicklook. And it's very fast.